# Unrecognized selector error with NSManagedObject getters/setters

Tags: iphone, ios, restkit

I receive the following error. I can't figure out why, since `latitude` and `longitude` have `@dynamic` in the implementation file, and they are not reserved words (as far as I can tell). I am using [RestKit](http://restkit.org) with Core Data.

```
2011-11-06 18:12:23.428 Dark Sky Finder[19407:11903] Creating observation site #1
2011-11-06 18:12:23.431 Dark Sky Finder[19407:11903] -[ObservationSite setLatitude:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x735fdf0
2011-11-06 18:12:23.431 Dark Sky Finder[19407:11903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ObservationSite setLatitude:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x735fdf0'
```

Code that causes the error:

```
if ([ObservationSite count:nil] == 0)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"Creating observation site #%i", i);
        ObservationSite *site = [ObservationSite object];
        site.observationSiteID = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
        site.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"James's Place #%i", i, nil];
        site.address = @"Somewhere";
        site.latitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:30.3605+i];
        site.longitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:-96.1852+i];
        [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] objectStore] save];
    }
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [ObservationSite fetchRequest];
NSArray *sites = [[ObservationSite objectsWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest] retain];
for (ObservationSite *site in sites)
{
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", site.name);
    NSLog(@"Address: %@", site.address);
    NSLog(@"Latitude: %@", site.latitude);
    NSLog(@"Longitude: %@", site.longitude);
}
```

`ObservationSite` header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>


@interface ObservationSite : NSManagedObject <MKAnnotation>
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D _coordinate;
    NSString *_title;
    NSString *_subtitle;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *observationSiteID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *latitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *longitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *address;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;

+ (ObservationSite *)mapAnnotation;
+ (ObservationSite *)mapAnnotationWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;
+ (ObservationSite *)mapAnnotationWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate title:(NSString *)title;
+ (ObservationSite *)mapAnnotationWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate title:(NSString *)title subtitle:(NSString *)subtitle;

@end
```

`ObservationSite` implementation file:

```
#import "ObservationSite.h"

@implementation ObservationSite

@synthesize coordinate = _coordinate;
@synthesize title = _title;
@synthesize subtitle = _subtitle;

@dynamic observationSiteID;
@dynamic latitude;
@dynamic longitude;
@dynamic address;
@dynamic name;

+ (ObservationSite *)mapAnnotation {
    return [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
}

+ (ObservationSite *)mapAnnotationWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    return [self mapAnnotationWithCoordinate:coordinate title:nil subtitle:nil];
}

+ (ObservationSite *)mapAnnotationWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate title:(NSString *)title {
    return [self mapAnnotationWithCoordinate:coordinate title:title subtitle:nil];
}

+ (ObservationSite *)mapAnnotationWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate title:(NSString *)title subtitle:(NSString *)subtitle {
    ObservationSite *annotation = [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
    annotation.coordinate = coordinate;
    annotation.title = title;
    annotation.subtitle = subtitle;
    return annotation;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoops — the attribute names I used in the `ObservationSite` header/implementation files were different than in the data model. I renamed them now to be the same, and it works fine.